# What is the actual difference between RFECV and RFE?

Tags: python, feature-extraction, feature-selection, rfe

I know one uses cross validation.But can anyone explain?? And also when to use each one?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably benefit from clarifying your acronyms. I would also recommend asking on Cross Validated, which is a sister website dedicated to statistics questions like this:

[Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)